# Unable to upload .ipa to iTunes using Application Loader

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa, application-loader

I'm trying to upload my iPhone .ipa file to iTunesconnect. I've even uploaded builds recently successfully to iTunes Connect through application loader. But from last two days while I am trying to upload ipa the following errors occur and .ipa is not being uploaded to iTunes Connect.

**An error occurred while processing the http request for the webdav upload**.

**An exception has occurred : Authorization required**

I have tried all the suggestions provided like tried uploading through application loader using different networks and Selected the option "DAV" in Application loader preferences but of no use.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please check your network

Comment: Network is good. I have even tried with other networks. Still same issue.

Comment: Do you try upload from XCode?

Comment: uploaded through Application loader itself after trying multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the OP's [self-answer from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260452/unable-to-upload-ipa-to-itunes-using-application-loader/44310113#comment64019588_38260452) (paraphrased):

After trying multiple times, I was finally able to upload the app through Application loader.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem all day today and from the duplicate questions and spark of recent activity on the topic today, it looks like a few others had it all at the same time.

I just tried again and it randomly started working for me. There was no problem with my network or with my ipa files so **all signs seem to point to it being an Apple problem with something being temporarily down**. Unfortunately, the solution in my case was just to wait it out and keep trying.