# Can't upload .ipa to iTunes using Application Loader

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have tried everything on this [SO post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429801/this-action-could-not-be-completed-try-again-22421)

and I still have this error through application loader:[image]

I have the latest xcode build 8.3.2 and have updated my .itmstransporter etc but everytime I go to upload I get stuck on verifying assets and then the error above pops up.

I also use cocoapods with firebase and have some missing files error if that matters? But I don't think it does.

What should I do? This is so frustrating

Comment: Dupe: [Unable to upload .ipa to iTunes using Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38260452/2415822).  Check your network and make sure you're iTunes Developer account is set up properly in Xcode.